# what does this regex match?

Tags: regex, perl

```
/[^\\]\]/
```

What does this regex match to?

Trying to match "]" somehow. I am not sure how exactly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It matches any single character that isn't a backslash `\`, followed by a closing square bracket `]`.

These strings match:

```
"[]" =~ /[^\\]\]/;       # []
"[abc]def" =~ /[^\\]\]/; # c]
```

These strings don't match:

```
"]" =~ /[^\\]\]/;        # No character preceding ]
"[\]" =~ /[^\\]\]/;      # Backslash preceding ]
```

If you're trying to match a `]` as long as it's not preceded by a `\`, use a negative lookbehind assertion instead of a negative character class:

```
/(?<!\\)\]/
```

(or see comments)

Comment: Which of course means it breaks if `]` is the first character of the string being matched.

Comment: Thanks BoltClock. I basically want to see if my string has [some text] in it.

Comment: Are you trying to match the text? What if the inner text also has square brackets?

Comment: If you want to grab the text inside try `/[([^\]]*?)]/`

Answer (score 4):

I know this is a Perl question, but if you have Python installed it can be helpful for debugging regular expressions like this.

```
$ python
>>> import re
>>> re.compile(r"[^\\]\]", re.DEBUG)
not_literal 92
literal 93
```

This tells us that it's looking for any character that isn't ASCII 92 (the backslash `\`) followed by the character ASCII 93 (the closing bracket `]`).

---

I see now that Perl has a similar feature. It seems less friendly.

```perl
$ perl
use re 'debug';
/[^\\]\]/;
Compiling REx "[^\\]\]"
Final program:
   1: ANYOF[\0-[\]-\377][{unicode_all}] (12)
  12: EXACT <]> (14)
  14: END (0)
anchored "]" at 1 (checking anchored) stclass ANYOF[\0-[\]-\377][{unicode_all}] minlen 2
```

Comment: Whoa. I wrote exactly this as you submitted. Killing my post.

Comment: There's a `re.DEBUG`modifier? _I did not know that!_ Thanks for the tip! +1