# using a perl regex in c

Tags: c, regex

[what does this regex match?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6643563/what-does-this-regex-match)

How can I use this regex in C?

I am getting error if I do:

```
if (regcomp(&reg, "/[^\\]\]/", REG_EXTENDED | REG_ICASE) != 0)
```

error:

```
warning: unknown escape sequence '\]'
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked when I escaped the backslashes and removed `/`s from both ends.

Answer (score 6):

I think you need to escape your backslashes:

```
from "/[^\\]\]/" to "/[^\\\\]\\]/"
```

Answer (score 0):

I like perl , and I also like C/C++. To make the best of both,
I wrote a github project to solve this issue.

please see:
    https://github.com/tlqtangok/perlcpp

a short example is here :

```
P_eval("$a=2;$a=$a**10;"); 
Int("a") ;   // a= 1024  


P_eval("@arr=(0..9);"; 
P_arr_Int_i("arr", 8 );  // => 8
```

Comment: You can use any perl regex in C/C++.